# Javascript - подгрузка контента с другой страницы

Tags: javascript

Данное действие делать умею, однако, есть одна деталь..

Вот код:

```
function load_content(url, into, from) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('GET', url);

    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 2) {
            enable(loading_ind);
        }

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            disable(loading_ind);

            var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.responseText, "text/html");
            document.getElementById(into).innerHTML = doc.getElementById(from).innerHTML;

            change_page(doc.title, doc.location);
        }
    }
    http.send(null);
}
```

Единственное, на каждую страницу при загрузке подключается функция ready, которая должна назначать каждому объекту свои onclick.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    ready();
});
```

Так вот, вопрос - как мне выполнить ту самую функцию, которая указана на другой странице без перезагрузки?

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался в вопросе.

Методом тыка я понял, что достаточно просто вызвать нужный метод, а в моём случае ready() после загрузки блока.

Спасибо всем, удачного кодинга!